# Django. How to kind of "spread" object when passing as with parameter to include?

Tags: django

I have a component which i include like that:

```
{% include "components/item_link.html" with target="_blank" href=link.href icon=link.icon text=link.text %}
```

There are lots of repetitions of `link.`. Is there a way to "spread" object and include it like that?

```
{% include "components/item_link.html" with target="_blank" ...link %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `link` variable directly like:

`{% include .... link=link %}`

Then in the included template use their single values as:

```
 link.href 
 link.icon 
 link.text
```

If you can't modify the included template code, you can create an intermediate template which assigns the above variables and call the original *include* with their respective `href=link.href icon=link.icon text=link.text` so you avoid to repeat everything every time you use it.

## Update

Add a `link` parameter, you can still use the parameters but then in the included template you can also detect if link is set when the parameter isn't set.

For example:

```
{% include "components/item_link.html" with target="_blank" link=link %}
```

in `components/item_link.html`:

```
<a href="{%if href%}{{href}}{%elif link%}{{link.href}}{%endif%}> ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to create intermediate template? Should it to be in another file? I don't really want to have `link.` in my component code too, I want to make these properties in template accessible by their name directly but at the same time make template include flexible to be called either with single object or with each parameter set separately

Comment: I edited the answer with a new approach, how about detecting if the desired parameter is there and fallback to a possible `link` parameter if not?

Comment: it is quite a lot to write every parameter such way